# How can I connect MapGuide Maestro to PostgreSQL/PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to connect my database PostgreSQL/PostGIS to MapGuide Maestro but it sends me an error message:

> [image]

Do you have some idea about this or can you help me about how I can connect it with my database postgis?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4, MapGuide open source 2.6.1 and MapGuide Maestro 6.0